# Mouse event doesn't pass evt object to function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to get a simple mouse event to work with D3.js (v5.7.0)
But for some reason it doesn't pass the EVT object to the function.

This is my current code:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");

const width = +$('#d3canvas #d3container').width();
const height = +$('#d3canvas #d3container').height();

console.log([width, height]);

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("pointer-events", "all")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoom));

function zoom() {
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

const g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

g.append("circle")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .attr("r", 40)
  .attr("cx", 50)
  .attr("cy", 20)
  .on("mousedown", test);

function test(evt) {
  console.log(evt);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#d3canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="d3canvas">
    <svg width="100%" height="800px" id="d3container"></svg>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

So now if I click on the circle the console writes Undefined.
I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814278/d3-js-mouse-events-not-working) (the mistake was a z-index in css which isn't the case for me)

I do see that that question uses d3.selectAll if I change my code to look like this it still won't work:

```
g.append("circle")
.style("fill", "black")
.attr("r", 40)
.attr("cx", 50)
.attr("cy", 20);

d3.selectAll("circle").on("mousedown", test);
```

I can get it to work by programmatically adding an eventListener to the circle like so:

```
let circle = g.append("circle")
.style("fill", "black")
.attr("r", 40)
.attr("cx", 50)
.attr("cy", 20);

circle._groups[0][0].addEventListener("mousedown", test);
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Question: Why isn't the mouse event object being passed to the test function?
And what is the right / better way to do something like this?

Comment: this problem? .bind(this)? or test =(evt)=>{console.log(evt)}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842099/how-do-i-get-the-mouse-coordinates-using-mousedown-in-d3

Comment: @epascarello The answer from that question does indeed solve the problem. I now see that I was trying out v3, v4 examples from bl.ocks.org which are appearantly not 100% compatible with v5?

Comment: use `d3.event`, maybe use `.on("click", test)`